# Why does the below code evaluate to false?

Tags: python, function

```
if all([0, 4, "Sample string"]):
    print "Yes"
else:
    print "No"
```

It always prints No despite the iterable having all the values. I can't understand what is making it evaluate to false.

Comment: `0` is not a true value.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 6):

`all()` returns true if *all values* are true, see the [function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

> Return `True` if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

`0` is not a true value:

```
>>> bool(0)
False
```

See the [*Truth Value Testing* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of the Python standard types documentation:

> The following values are considered false:
>
> [...]
>
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0.0, 0j.

Answer (score 1):

Your iterable contains a `0`, and 0 evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python the integer 0 is equal to False.

Comment: True, but `all()` doesn't care about equality. `None` is not equal to `False`, nor are `0.0` or `()` or `[]`, but all those values *test as false in a Boolean context*, which is what matters here.

Answer (score -1):

To check if the array contains boolean value "False" anywhere (as I guess 
you had intended to do), simply do:

```
if all(map(lambda v: v is not False, [0, 4, "Sample string"])):
    print "Yes"
else:
    print "No"
```

Comment: I actually wanted to check whether all the values are present i.e. "not null" so 0 is an acceptable value. Though I had forgotten that it will be equal to a boolean False.